# Jena - How to link a resource to a property?

Tags: java, properties, resources, jena

I am working at a framework for implementing Europeana Data Model (EDM) for a particular data structure and I have an issue when I want to add a property. For example, considering the following simple example (**using Apache Jena 3.9**):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String NS = "http://my.com/";
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.setNsPrefix("edm", EDM_TEST.getURI());
    model.setNsPrefix("skos", SKOS.getURI());

    Resource repository = model.createResource(NS + "testing_agent");
    repository.addProperty(RDF.type, EDM_TEST.Agent);
    repository.addProperty(SKOS.altLabel, model.createLiteral("Vasile Alecsandri Museum"));
    repository.addProperty(SKOS.prefLabel, model.createLiteral("Vasile Alecsandri National Museum"));

    Resource providedCHO = model.createResource(NS + "testing_cho");
    providedCHO.addProperty(RDF.type, EDM_TEST.ProvidedCHO);
    providedCHO.addProperty(EDM_TEST.currentLocation, repository);

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    model.write(out, "RDF/XML");
    String result = out.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The result it seems to be ok:

```
<edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://my.com/testing_cho">
    <edm:currentLocation>
      <edm:Agent rdf:about="http://my.com/testing_agent">
        <skos:prefLabel>Vasile Alecsandri National Museum</skos:prefLabel>
        <skos:altLabel>Vasile Alecsandri Museum</skos:altLabel>
      </edm:Agent>
    </edm:currentLocation>
</edm:ProvidedCHO>
```

but it isn't ok, because EDM does not allow an inner object for **currentLocation** property. So, I need to generate the following output for currentLocation property:

```
<edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://my.com/testing_cho">
    <edm:currentLocation rdf:resource="http://my.com/testing_agent"/>
</edm:ProvidedCHO>
<edm:Agent rdf:about="http://my.com/testing_agent">
    <skos:prefLabel>Vasile Alecsandri National Museum</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:altLabel>Vasile Alecsandri Museum</skos:altLabel>
</edm:Agent>
```

How can I separately create the repository resource (the Agent) and link to **currentLocation** property from providedCHO resource as I explained above?

Comment: I tested Apache Jena 3.0.0 and it seems that it have the desired behaviour... but it isn't a long term solution.
If anyone know the solution for Apache Jena 3.9, please leave it here :)

Comment: Unfortunately neither Jena 3.0.0 it isn't good for my requirements because it leads the "<rdf:Description" tags even you set the type Agent or ProvidedCHO....

Comment: It is not metodologically correct to "validate" RDF/XML serialization which can be different. Say them they should learn how to parse and validate RDF(using e.g. SHACL). It seems they know how to parse and validate XML only.

Comment: In your case, `model.getWriter("RDF/XML-ABBREV").setProperty("prettyTypes", ...); model.write(System.out,"RDF/XML-ABBREV");` could take effect, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Jena 3.0.1 and 3.9.0 is that  the default choice of RDF/XMl writer changed from plain to pretty.

More control of the choice of format details is available with

```
RDFDataMgr.write(..,..,RDFFormat.RDFXML_ABBREV)

RDFDataMgr.write(..,..,RDFFormat.RDFXML_PLAIN)
```

Even more control is available with:

http://jena.staging.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html#advanced-rdfxml-output

To create a very particular XML schema, you may need to get the data out and then run XSLT.